# Where i can finde " woocommerce_before_account_navigation" hook and fuction file

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, overriding, hook-woocommerce

This is a code of my account navigation template and i need to change and add some classes to the template that rendered in do_action code that callback a function, i was search in most files of my woocomerce but i can not finde the template file for  hook "do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_navigation' )"

```
    <?php

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
    }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_navigation' );
    ?>
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

This hook `woocommerce_before_account_navigation` can be seen at `plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/navigation.php` line 22

```
    /**
     * My Account navigation
     *
     * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/navigation.php.
     *
     * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
     * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
     * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
     * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
     * the readme will list any important changes.
     *
     * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
     * @package WooCommerce\Templates
     * @version 2.6.0
     */

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
      exit;
    }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_navigation' );
```

Comment: any hook callback a function, function will import template file, i know this hook where is used, i need to find function that hook call it to find where template file are.

Comment: Search in theme files for the hook `woocommerce_before_account_navigation`